# Open file in specific Visual Studio Code window from external terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code

If the user has multiple Visual Studio Code windows open, is there a way to open a file from an external terminal in an **specific existing  window**?

I know one can just do `code <file>` to open a file in the *last active window*. I am wondering if there is a way to open it in a specific existing window (perhaps using the workspace name).

Answer (score 0):

Use the -n or --new- option in the terminal

```
code -n <file>
```

Or

```
code --new-window <file>
```

edit: code -h gives you a list of possible commands

Answer (score 0):

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line

```
 -n or --new-window
    
code --new-window <file>
```

Opens a new session of VS Code instead of restoring the previous session (default).

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking to open it in a specific existing window, not new window. I added existing to the question description to make it more clear.